# How to add vertical rule on a compound TextView

Tags: android

I'm using a compound TextView inside a `<RelativeLayout>` with an image on top of the text via `drawableTop`. What I want, is to be able to add a vertical rule/border on the right side of the compounded TextView.

This is how the image looks like right now:

[image]

This is how I want it to look like:

[image]

This is how I'm making the compounded `TextView`

```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/searchRadiusText"
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingTop="2dp"
       android:paddingBottom="2dp" 
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
       android:text="100 km"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_search_radius"
       android:drawablePadding="15dp" />
```

The `TextView` and `SeekBar` are inside a `RelativeLayout`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you try drawableRight?

Comment: I did but the `drawablePadding` is messing everything up :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Included a `<view>` after `TextView` and styled it to display a border on the right.
Here's how:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/searchRadiusText"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="100 km"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_search_radius"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp" />

    <View
    android:id="@+id/vertical_border"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchRadiusText"
    android:background="@color/btn_gray_light"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
```

and then, I added the `<SeekBar>` with `android:layout_toRightOf` attribute with `view`'s ID.